# Using Entity Framework for Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I am pretty new to Entity Framework. I know how to use it generally and also managed to call stored procedures.

However, due to business reasons (legacy DB), we are having majority of business logic in stored procedures, which means C# code is limited to calling stored procedures with appropriate parameters and getting results.

So, I wanted to understand from gurus and their practical experience, apart from having ready-made objects created which can be used for processing, what advantage will it offer in such case?

Thanks for sharing knowledge :-)

Comment: Having *ready-made* and nice-to-use C# objects ***IS*** a huge benefit! So you won't have to mess around with untyped rows and columns and you can dump (or not write in the first place) all that messy, boring "glue code" !

Comment: Probably this article will help you https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/calling-stored-procedures-from-entity-framework.aspx?m=1

Comment: @marc_s Agree, That's a huge benefit and I am aware of it. Needed to understand any other advantage before making decision of using it.

Comment: I would say if you just want to call stored procs and map those results to POCO's then just use a micro ORM like dapper. EF has performance overheads.